# PHP variable assignment needs parentheses

Tags: php

I wrote some code and found it didn't work as I expected.

For example, the following would return `false` or throw an exception, `Undefined variable: a`:

```
if ($a = 12 && $a == 12) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

I fixed it by wrapping the assignment in parentheses:

```
if (($a = 12) && $a == 12) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

It was just a lucky guess. I'm wondering why the parentheses are needed and I haven't found anything that explains why.

Comment: Why on earth are you setting a variable as 12 and then checking it is 12?

Comment: @user1672694, I assume that the OP originally had something more complicated and reduced it to a MWE for posting on Stackoverflow, to make the problem more clear.

Comment: @merlin2011: it's still unlikely to have the same variable assignment and check together. If it's a simplification, then the original solution is poorly designed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because of [operator precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). The assignment operator `=` has a lower precedence than `&&`, so without the parenthesis you are effectively doing the following.

```
if ($a = (12 && $a == 12))
```

Observe that the second `$a` is not yet defined before the assignment happens, because it has to be evaluated before the assignment can happen.